# Thymeleaf - Configure mail subject in template

Tags: thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf templates for generating email contents and send using spring mailSender. Is there any option to specify the email subject within the thymeleaf template itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define fragments in your template and render those parts only.

```
<div th:fragment="subject">
    Mail subject
</div>
<div th:fragment="body">
    Mail body
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I defined my mail template like `<html>
 <body>
  <div th:remove="all">
   <div th:fragment="subject">
    Mail subject
   </div>
  </div>
  Mail Body
 </body>
</html>` and used separate calls to render subject and body.

Comment: can you give example of how you "used separate calls to render subject and body" plz ?

Answer (score 0):

That's a basic HTML thing

```
<a href="mailto:admin@example.com?subject=This is my subject">Send mail</a>
```

you can add also the `?body=` if you want to *add content in your mail*.

**Edit**: According to your comment, you want to put a input on a page and write a subject and get it in Java.

Put a form with an input in your thymeleaf template and post it to your server, get the value in your controller and use it to send your mail.

Do you need code example for this ?

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my case, the mail is send from java code using spring mailSender. I am using Thymeleaf template engine to render mail body and pass it to mailSender along with 'to address' and subject. Now I am looking for an option to specify the subject in thymeleaf template itself and retrieve it from my java code to pass to mailSender.

Comment: Modified my answer. Let me know if you need more than that.

Comment: I am using thymeleaf templates only to capture email content and is working in a non-web environment.